# awk manipulation of file

Tags: awk

I have a big file in this format, whose first few lines I am showing you including the header.

```
gene    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8
G1*1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
G2*2    0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
G3*3    0   0   2   2   44  44  62  62
G4*4    22  0   46  0   1308    7   1773    4
```

First line with the gene is the header line. I want to keep it as it is and then I want to split the remaining line with FS = *, so that now I have a file looking like this as output

```
gene    coord   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8
G1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
G2  2   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
G3  3   0   0   2   2   44  44  62  62
G4  4   22  0   46  0   1308    7   1773    4
```

So also I want to place an extra field in the header line named 'coord', so that when i split the subsequent lines I have everything ordered.

I know how to use awk for splitting but header line is what is confusing me

```
awk -F '*' -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2}' ##This is for 2nd line and onwards
```

Answer (score 5):

The header line is a special case, so you can handle it as a special case.

```
awk -F '*' -v OFS='\t' \
  'NR == 1 { sub(/^gene/, "&" OFS "coord"); print; next }
  { print $1, $2 }'
```

Comment: Can you explain what is OFS doing in sub part??

Comment: @user3138373 It's just a tab to separate gene and coord into separate columns.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach:

```
awk -F '[ \t*]' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{$2="coord\t"$2;print;next}{$1=$1}1' file
```

- The input file wasn't clear for me, so I used 3 field separators: space, tab, and `*`. You can probably remove something from the list if you now your input better.
- `$1=$1` basically does nothing, it is needed to reorganize fields (use new field separator everywhere)
- final `1` is used just to print everything after modification.

Comment: Hi can you explain the code
with [\t*] I think you are spiltting on 2 delimiters tab and *. Can you explain $1=$1 and 1 thing?

Comment: @user3138373 Your input file wasn't clear for me, so I used 3 field separators: space, tab, and star. You can probably remove something from the list if you now your input better. `$1=$1` basically does nothing, it is needed to reorganize fields (use new field separator, a tab, everywhere), and last `1` is used to just print everything.

Answer (score 4):

Is the use of `awk` an absolute requirement?  This seems more like a job for `sed`:

```
sed '1s/gene/&    coord/;2,$s/\*/  /'
```

which is just about self-explanatory:

- `1s/gene/&    coord/` – on the first line, change “gene” to “gene    coord”.
- `2,$s/\*/  /` – on the second line through the end of the file,
  change literal “*” to white space.