# tab separation of the file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file with seq likes this

```
ATCGTTTCTCAGCCTTTTGGCAAGACCAAGTGTAGTATCTGTTCTTATCAGATATTGGTATCTGCAGGCACTCCTGGAACCAAT
ATCACTTCTCAACCTTTTGACTAAGATCAAGTGTAATATCTATCTTTATCAGTTTAATATCTGAGATCTCCTTTATCTGAGGACAATATATTTAATGGATTTTTGGAACAGAGAGAAGGAATAGGAGCTTGTCCTGTCCACTCCATGCATTGACCTGGTATTGCAGGACCTCCAGAAACACCACCCCCTCC
ACGCATTATCCGCCTATTGGCTAAAAACAAATGTAGTATCTGTTCCTATCAGTTAAAGCATCAAATGTGGTCTCTAAGTTCAGGGAATTAAATTAATATTTGGAATTGGGAGATGGTTTGGGAGCTTGCTCTATCCTCTCCATGCCTCAGCATGTAATTGCAATGCTTTCAGGAGTGGTGCATTCCTT
```

It has 3 lines.
I want for each line each letter gets separated by tab and then want to store it in another file. How can i do it.

Comment: With such questions you should always give an example for the expected output.

Comment: It's a DNA sequence... How long is the strand?  ie you should split tabs at the end of the chain.  Add more info as Hauke states.

Answer (score 5):

If I have understood your intention correctly then this does it:

```
sed -e 's/./&\t/g' -e $'s/\t$//' file
```

The second replacement deletes the tab at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -ne 'print join "\t", split //' file > new_file
```

Comment: If you like golf: `perl -ne '$,="\t";print split//' file > new_file`

Answer (score 2):

In `awk`:

```
awk -F '' -vOFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file > new_file
```

Borrowed the idiom `{$1=$1}1` from [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174716/26909) to one of your other questions.

This sets the field separator to nothing (`-F ''`), which means that each record is read character-by-character. The output field separator is set to a TAB character (`-vOFS='\t'`) and the idiom `{$1=$1}1` is (as far as I can tell) a no-op that has the side effect of causing `awk` to insert the `OFS` between every two fields before printing them all.

Comment: pretty good. not everybody breaks it down by arguments. someday I'll learn how to use `awk` probably - and I'll need it broken down that way I expect. thanks.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks. I have promised myself to learn proper `awk` one day, too :)

Comment: I wonder if that `{$1=$1}1` thing is anything like `sed`'s `s/.\{0,1\}/ /g`? You know - matching the null field between the strings? That's pretty cool, anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv Probably not. As far as I can tell, `$1=$1` doesn't do anything but tricks `awk` into thinking the first field has been re-assigned so that it knows to insert the OFS between adjacent fields. The `1` at the end is to simply return a "true" value and cause `awk` to print the current record by default.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give `fold` a go:

```
tr \\n \\r <infile | fold -w1 | tr '\r\n'  '\n\t' >outfile
```

I preprocess `fold`'s input w/ `tr` by replacing the instream `\n`ewline characters w/ `\r`eturns. `fold` is printing a `\n`ewline character for every column in input - each of your capital letters - but it resets its counter on `\r`eturns and so when `tr` does the final post-processing and converts `fold`'s `\n`ewlines to `\t`abs there are no extra `\t`ab characters in output. The output is three lines with a `\t`ab character following each character but the last on each line.